# automate available seat selection with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I would like to automate the process of updating a page where I can see a set of seats (in blue if they are not available) until they are free (they turn green) and select one when it is free. how could i solve this problem??

---

Comment: Hello,

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to see that you're making use of this platform to resolve your programming issues.

Your question lacks key information needed for a helpful answer. Here's what you need to improve:

1. **Website URL:** Share the URL of the website you're working on. This is important as website structures can vary.

2. **Code Samples:** If possible, provide some code snippets that you've tried. This helps others understand your approach and where you might be getting stuck.

3. **Problem Specifics:** Elaborate on your exact challenge – is it detecting the seat's c

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the URL to the website that you're trying to select seats, it's impossible to give you an accurate answer.

Having said that, is this what you're looking for?

```py
# == Necessary imports =========================================================
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# NOTE: You might need to specify the path to your chromedriver.
#       For example: executable_path=r'/Users/erikingwersen/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64 (1)/chromedriver'
#       You can download chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/erikingwersen/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64 (1)/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

VACANT_FILL = "#90c84f"                                         # The fill color of vacant seats
OCCUPIED_FILL = "#337ab7"                                       # The fill color of occupied seats
URL = "https://sales.ticketsforfun.com.br/#/event/o-rei-leao"   # The URL to navigate to
MAX_TRIES = 10                                                  # Maximum number of tries before giving up

driver.get(URL)                                                 # Navigate to your URL

while MAX_TRIES >= 0:
    try:
        # Wait for a seat to become free
        # Vacant seats have a property fill="#90c84f" (green)
        seat = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(@fill, {VACANT_FILL!r})]"))
        )
        seat.click()      # Click the free seat
        break
    except Exception:  # noqa
        driver.refresh()  # If no free seat was found, refresh the page and try again
    finally:
        MAX_TRIES -= 1
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Maximum number of tries exceeded")

driver.quit()
```

The above example works for the following webpage: https://sales.ticketsforfun.com.br/#/event/o-rei-leao

[image]

Inspecting the page, you'll find that available seats have an attribute named `"fill"`, that for vacant seats, the attribute has a value of `"#90c84f"`.

[image]

Therefore, in the above script, we're searching for clickable elements that contain the attribute `"fill"` equal to `"#90c84f"`:

```py
while MAX_TRIES >= 0:
    try:
        # ...
        seat = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(@fill, {VACANT_FILL!r})]"))
        )
        # ...
```

### NOTES

To use the script, make the following changes:

- Replace the value from `URL` with your actual webpage
- Replace `//*[contains(@fill, '#90c84f')]` with the **XPath** that contains the attribute name, and value from your website.